# Negation of this statement

Tags: predicate-logic

Having some trouble negating this expression

\begin{align}
\forall x \in N, x^2 \in N \text { and } (1 / 2x) \notin N
\end{align}

"Indicate whether the negated statement is true."

When I read it out loud it makes sense to me.

"For all x in the natural numbers, x^2 is also in the natural numbers (which makes sense) and 1 / 2x is not in the natural numbers (which also makes sense).

My go at negating this

\begin{align}
\lnot \forall x \in N, x^2 \in \text { and } (1 / 2x) \in N 
\end{align}

Is this correct? Seems wrong to me.

The question also asks not to keep the negation symbol at the front, which is confusing me even more.

Any tips would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: 1/2x is ambiguous. Do you mean (1/2)x or 1/(2x)?

Comment: Oh I meant 1/(2x)! Sorry about that, still getting used to this formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you negate a logical expression, you convert $\forall$'s to $\exists$'s, and ANDs to ORs (and vice versa). So the negation would be

$$
\exists x \in N, x^2 \notin N \text{ or } (1/2x) \in N
$$

So assuming N denotes the natural numbers, the negation is not true, since you cannot find any natural number satisfying either of the predicates.

Comment: Than you so much, I did not know negate x^2 in N that way!! Very helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

$\exists x \in N$ sucht that $x^2 \notin N$ or $\frac{1}{2x} \in N$.

Comment: Is the last part not negated? Why is that?

Comment: I was looking to your negation and got it wrong, just edited now

Comment: Oh that makes more sense, thank you so much! That clarified everything, I've been stuck on 10+ questions because I didn't know you can negate x^2 in N in such way. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Just remember you're not negating x$^2 \in N$ and rather the sentence, that is, $\forall p \in N, P \wedge \sim Q$, which is $\exists p \in N; \sim P \vee Q$.

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

> Indicate whether the negated statement is true.

Assuming that $1/2x$ means $\frac{1}{2}x$, $4 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\frac{1}{2}(4)=2 \in \mathbb{N},$ in which case the statement is false.

---

If the $1/2x$ means $\frac{1}{2x}$, then the statement is true.